# How can I load a response from requests.get() in the browser?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm making some requests, in the console. The responses of these contain relevant data both in the headers (Location) the status code (302), and the cookies (some authentication credentials).

My code looks basically like this: `response = requests.get('<url>', cookies={'auth': 'secret stuff'}, allow_redirects=False)`

Now that I have my response, is there an easy way to forward it to the browser?

For starters, if I could just write this http response to a file, that would be awesome. 
How I thought about doing this, is so:

```
with open(my_file_path, 'w') as thefile:
  thefile.write('HTTP/1.1 302 Temporary Redirect\n')
  for header, value in response.headers.items():
  thefile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(header, value)
```

...and then I'd open netcat with `nc -l 9999`, open the browser, go to `localhost:9999`, paste the thing from my file in there, hit enter, and see that thing in a browser.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could try [`selenium-requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium-requests/).

Comment: It may be useful to use a proxy server written in python. That way you can modify the cookies in your code (which presumably is what you are testing with this experiment), then visit the URL in question via the browser through your proxy server.

Comment: @chrisd1100 I agree, depending on what exactly what OP wants to do, that might be an easier approach. https://mitmproxy.org/ is awesome for things like that (allows to freeze requests/responses and manipulate them in flight)  - and it happens to be written in Python :-)